# Grails domain class: unique constraint for multiple columns

Tags: grails, orm, unique-constraint, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

Suppose a simple Grails domain class:

```
class Account {
    String countryId;

    String userName;

    String password;

    static constraints = {
        ...???...
    }
}
```

It is required that user names are unique for a particular *countryId*, thus there must be a *unique* contraint on two columns. How to express this in the *constraints* definition?

Comment: I was browsing the web and in particular stackoverflow without finding an answer. In the end, I found the solution in the [Grails reference](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Constraints/unique.html) although all other Grails documentation examples only contaning the single column case. Didn't know that self-answering is not allowed within 8 hours

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
userName(unique: ['countryId'])
```

You can include as many other properties in the array that make up the other properties that must be considered in the "unique" constraint on the username.

So, for example if you wanted to make `userName` unique within a `countryId` and `provinceId` it would look like this:

```
userName(unique: ['countryId', 'provinceId']
```

Comment: In grails 3 it is written "userName unique: 'countryId'"
http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html

Comment: @CarlosParraga that's just a variant of the same thing. That same syntax can be used with versions of Grails prior to 3.x as well.